# Spring JpaRepository findAll, Java 8 Stream, Connection has been abandoned

Tags: java, spring, database-connection, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I'm using Spring Boot and trying to do a findAll query in mu repository which should return a Stream of results:

```
public interface MyThingRepository extends JpaRepository<MyThing, String> {
   Stream<MyThing> findAll();
}

public class MyScheduledJobRunner {

   @Autowired 
   private MyThingRepository myThingRepository;

   public void run() {
      try (Stream<MyThing> myThingsStream : myThingRepository.findAll()) {
        myThingsStream.forEach(myThing -> {
           // do some stuff
        });
        // myThingsStream.close(); // <- at one point even tried that, though the stream is wrapped in an auto-closing block. anyway, it did not help
       System.out.println("All my things processed.");
     }
     System.out.println("Exited the auto-closing block.");
   }
}
```

Output that I get is:

```
All my things processed.
Exited the auto-closing block.
o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2865b7d5]:java.lang.Exception
|   at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1061)
...
at MyScheduledJobRunner.run(MyScheduledJobRunner:52)
```

MyScheduledJobRunner:52 is:

```
try (Stream<MyThing> myThingsStream : myThingRepository.findAll()) {
```

As per documentation, when using Streams in JpaRepositories you should always close them after usage. Since they implement AutoCloseable then you can use try with resources block. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming

> A Stream potentially wraps underlying data store specific resources and must therefore be closed after usage. You can either manually close the Stream using the close() method or by using a Java 7 try-with-resources block.

There's even an example at the documentation that does it exactly the same way I do. So I am doing all that documentation says as far as I can tell, but still I get an exception 30 seconds after the operation. So apparently the connection is not closed and is left hanging. Why is that and how could I overcome this?

I've tried with Postgres 9.5 and MariaDB as a database. I am using the newest possible connectors/drivers and Tomcat connection pooling that is configured through spring boot's properties like that:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useSSL=false
    username: user
    password: password
    initial-size: 10
    max-active: 100
    max-idle: 50
    min-idle: 10
    max-wait: 15000
    test-while-idle: true
    test-on-borrow: true
    validation-query: SELECT 1
    validation-query-timeout: 5
    validationInterval: 30000
    time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 30000
    min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 60000
    removeAbandonedTimeout: 60
    remove-abandoned: true
    log-abandoned: true
```

Comment: I'm sure it returns List and Page. I'm not sure if it returns stream. Whatever. Did you write annotations like: @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME), @Service and do you have Creators (@Configuration) for DataSource Beans, Repository Beans, ServiceBeans?

Comment: Yes. All my annotations and beans are set. If they would not be set, then my database stuff would not work at all, but it does work well. Just this nasty abandoned connection error that I do not like in my logs. This is just a minimal example. And if you look at the documentation link I provided, then you'll see that Spring Boot JPA with Java 8 has support for Stream in addition to Page and Collection. The motivation why I am using Stream instead of a Page or Collection is that the set of MyThings  is potentially humongous and I can not read it to memory.

Comment: And if you try to get a List<MyThing>, do you get it?

Comment: I'm not doing it that way usually. I also declare private final myThingRepository and make an @Autowired constructor.. I don't mean this is the reason, but whatever.

Comment: Yes, i will. I also get the Stream<MyThing>. Problem is not in not getting it, problem is rhat the db connection is not properly closed after reading the database entries.

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring JPA, but is  `Stream<MyThing> findAll()` a method which you implement or generated by Spring?

Comment: I am also doing some stuff like autowiring in my actual code differently, but thats irrelevant since it is a MWE

Comment: Spring will impliment this method itself in runtime. I just have to write interface. Thats how spring jpa works.

Comment: How to start a chat here?

Comment: Because I have a project I would deal; Maybe this could be helpful

Comment: Does this problem only occur then using `Stream` (and not when using methods return `List`)? It can be assumed that Spring probably releases its resources correctly. Your link also says "Not all Spring Data modules currently support Stream<T> as a return type." Which version of Spring (Data) are you using, there were some bugs related to Streams: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-742

Comment: After some debugging and discussion with Spring Boot developers I decided to create an issue in Spring Data's issue tracker: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-917

Answer (score 0):

in pool configuration  just u need to add : 
"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"

Comment: Please elaborate why and how that property would help me?

Comment: u can find the information in this Link : http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency   ,,,, this property Reset a time out

Comment: It sounds off, that in order to use out of the box Spring functionality that is well documented in a way to not get exceptions, I have to set some random Tomcat parameter. At the very best in this case, it is a documentation bug IMO. Anyway, I could not get this to work (ClassNotFound)